# ASP.NET Core Web API CORS error on Firefox but okay on Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, cors

I have a React and ASP.NET Core 2.2 SPA that has a CORS issue with Firefox but is okay in Chrome and Edge. I've created a little test rig that consists of the ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API template with CORS enabled and a Create React App that uses `fetch` to call the web API.

Here's the ASP.NET Core `Startup.cs` with CORS enabled:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
    }));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Here's the React page that requests the data:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("loading ...")  
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("https://localhost:44335/api/values").then(res=>res.json()).then(body=>{
      setData(JSON.stringify(body));
    })
  },[]);
  return <p>{data}</p>
}
```

This works fine in Chrome and Edge but I get the following error in Firefox:

[image]

Am I enabling CORS correctly? or am I missing something else? Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you try when both reactjs/dotnet systems are running under http or https?  Here you have a mixed protocol http for reactjs and https for dotnet core

Comment: Yes, thanks hugo, it was the mix of http and https that was causing the problem. FF is happy if I use the same protocol for both backend and frontend

Answer (score 3):

On FireFox, the protocols must match for CORS policy origins. If your WebAPI has `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` configured and your react app is being served from non SSL, you will get a CORS block. So either:

- Disable `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` in dev/local environment
- Host your dev/local react app with SSL
- Turn of SSL in iis express for the WebAPI

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but I faced the same problem right now and my solution was not mentioned above.

Currently Firefox is very restrictive with self-signed development SSL certificates. So if you run both API and SPA frontend in SSL mode:

**Make sure both are opened in Firefox and add exceptions for both developer certificates!**

In my case I had the API only opened in Chrome and so the exception was still missing in Firefox. Hence the SSL-connection failed.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another facet to this...

I had a case where Firefox would give me a CORS error when calling a specific controller, but would work fine on other controllers in the same WebAPI instance.

What I found was on the 'problem' controller, it was actually throwing an exception.  The exception in this case it was a 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException'.  When I fixed the problem, the CORS errors went away.  Probably other server-level exceptions would cause the same thing.

Who knows why FF would interpret an exception as a CORS error...